# Preventing auto focus of EditText in an AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

I am having some trouble preventing an EditText within an AlertDialog automatically obtaining focus and displaying the keyboard.

The presenting activity has `windowSoftInputMode=stateHidden` and EditTexts within that don't get focus when the activity loads. But when the dialog is shown the keyboard automatically appears.

How do I prevent my AlertDialog from showing the keyboard when it is shown?

Comment: Set the attributes android:focusable="true" and android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you have a custom layout for your AlertDialog you can use a dummy view that get the focus instead of your edittext:

```
<!-- Dummy view -->
<View
    android:layout_width="0dp" 
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:focusable="true" 
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>
```

Try to put that view before your edittext.

Comment: Faced the same issue hundreds of times and is always so annoying :D. Happy it helped you.

Comment: Note that `focusable="true"` alone is not enough

Comment: Even though this is the best and easiest solution, this is still kind of a hack. xD

Comment: Yes, it's definitely a hack. However, if your EditText is inside of something like a LinearLayout though, you can set the `focusable` and `focusableInTouchMode` attributes on that LinearLayout instead of adding a 'Dummy view'.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following while creating your edit text

```
 <EditText
           android:id="@+id/E_table_no"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="38dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
           android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
           android:singleLine="true"
           android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Force hide the Android SoftKeyboard using the code below ,

```
EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditText);  
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
      Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```